# Is it acceptable to lie that one is Jewish because it might be embarassing for people to know you are not Jewish?

Tags: halacha, sheker-false

If you know the answer to this, I'd like to know where your answer is sourced and where I can learn more about it.

Furthermore, if the person claims embarrassment, how do we know that this is not just a fake reason to justify his actions. We can't prove or disprove his emotions, at least not in a straightforward way.

Comment: This is a bit circular because it would only apply to a non Jew. And the 613 mitzvot don’t apply to them. So it is not clear what you are asking. Are you asking what Halacha has to say about lying because one is embarrassed for others to know the truth? But then it would have to be a different scenario

Comment: I don't understand why this would be forbidden...

Comment: Halacha is obviously not based on feelings, but a person who lies about being Jewish, coupled with other suspicious activities are red flags for me, e.g. a narcissistic character, malicious intentions, and so on. The Torah suggests a degree of auspiciousness. I guess the question is more about what Halacha tells the recipient of the lie and liar to do vis-a-vis the liar.

Comment: One reason why a gentile claiming to be Jewish is problematic is that gentiles are prohibited to keeping sections of the Torah. Rav Schochet said that gentiles keeping the whole Torah is tantamount to theft. There are mitzvot that gentiles should not do, e.g. put on tallis gadol, tefillin, being called up to the Torah, being counted for a minyan. A gentile who says a bracha for kerias hatorah may be tantamount to saying a bracha in vain. Moreover, a gentile who performs these mitzvah give the false impression of being someone they are not, which seems problematic.

Comment: Since a prohibition from lying is a logical injunction, it is also incumbent upon gentiles to be honest. There is also the idea that gentiles should honour G-d's name by not lying. It's sourced in at least 4 different sections in the Divine Code.